# Can anyone help me in the below scenario in Talend

Tags: talend

Can anyone help me in the below scenario in Talend:-

Create a mapping based on the following scenario,

Source Structure and its data,

```
STORE_NAME  Varchar2 (20)
Q1_SALES    number (10, 4)
Q2_SALES    number (10, 4)
Q3_SALES    number (10, 4)
Q4_SALES    number (10, 4)
```

DB_Store_Source: (flat file)

```
STORE_NAME  Q1_SALES    Q2_SALES    Q3_SALES    Q4_SALES

XYZ 100 200 150 900
ABC 111 222 789 763
DEF 333 444 555 2000
```

FF_Store_Source: (Flat File)

```
STORE_NAME  Q1_SALES    Q2_SALES    Q3_SALES    Q4_SALES

XYZ 100 200 150 900
ABC 111 222 789 763
ZZZ 200 200 200 300
```

Target structure,

```
Store_Target:

SNo integer,
STORE_NAME varchar2 (20),
QUARTER_NAME varchar2 (20),
SALES_PER_QUARTER number (10, 4)
```

From the above scenario, create a mapping to merge the data from DB_Store_Source and FF_Store_Source and pass the unique record into Store_Target.
SNo should be populated with sequence generated value (first record Starting with 1000) and rest of the columns populates from source based on Normalization

I am able to fetch using the unique rows. Even I am able to normalize but couldn't achieve the last part i.e how to store quarter_name.using the taggregaterow sum function i am able to get sum function

Comment: A little bit unreadable. Can you precise more?

Comment: See wat u have to do u have to create a job in talend which will have a target like below        Store_Target:

SNo integer,
STORE_NAME varchar2 (20),
QUARTER_NAME varchar2 (20),
SALES_PER_QUARTER number (10, 4)  But in the 2 source flat files we have Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4. how to do it? Target will be something like this    SNO,STORE_NAME,QUARTER_NAME,SALES_PER_QUARTER
1001,XYZ,Q1,100
1002,XYZ,Q2,200
1003,XYZ,Q3,150
1004,XYZ,Q4,900
1005,ABC,Q1,111

Comment: @Abhijit: Basically what i understand,you need to do PIVOT ,meaning rows to column ,so you can use below component in Talend https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tPivotToColumnsDelimited

Comment: @GauravSoni His scenario is not PIVOT. This is UNPIVOT scenario.

Comment: @Abhijit Provide screenshot of what have you done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the below result, then use `tsplitrow` component

[image]

`tsplitrow` component properties are in below image

[image]

**Note: Use `tsplitrow` component after you have taken unique records.**

Comment: hi your answer was useful.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below solution as shown in the screenshot at the bottom of the question to achieve your output result.

I have followed below steps in sequence:-

1. Read the data of both the FF_STORE and DB_STORE and propagate all the records of both the inputs to tHashOutput.
2. In next step I have taken the data from tHashOutput to tUnite component to merge both the data source records.
3. In the further step used tSplitRow to split Quarter column to be populated in the Quarter_Name column.
4. Then using tUniqRow removes the duplicates based on the key column.

Please refer the below image

[solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBnO5.jpg)